# Subtitles or how can a text object be edited before a frame is rendered?

Tags: python, animation

A text object's text is supposed to show information like a subtitle. How could the text be changed on a frame # based trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [application handler](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_10/bpy.app.handlers.html?highlight=frame_change_pre#bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre) could be used to read subtitle data and display it by editing the text object.

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent


@persistent
def frame_change(arg):
    print("Load Handler:", bpy.data.filepath)
    t = bpy.data.objects["Text"]
    label = ("Frame # %d" % bpy.context.scene.frame_current)
    t.data.body = label

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(frame_change)
```

Comment: There's no need for the `@persistent` decorator, unless you want the app handler callback to survive .blend file loading (also new file). [API Docs](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_10/bpy.app.handlers.html#persistent-handler-example)