# Video Sequence Editor - How to make subtitles?

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, text-object

Is there a way of adding Subtitles directly in the VSE? Or do I have to make an animation of text meshes and add it to the video *via a Scene strip*?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6971/subtitles-or-how-can-a-text-object-be-edited-before-a-frame-is-rendered you just need to read a file with subtitles-text and start/end frame (or duration)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Blender 2.76 (or more detailled, since the [Gooseberry Branch](https://gooseberry.blender.org/gooseberry-in-blender-master/)) there is a great new [Text Effect](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.76/Sequencer#Text_Effect) Strip feature which will do the job for you! Mikeycal Meyers already made a great [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-qMPzhFNwg) on this topic.

Just Add <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> an E̲ffect Strip... T̲ext. You can animate it's opacity if needed and change it's size and position.
[image: Add a Text Strip]

Comment: we prefer detailed answers over Link-Olny answers. Can you please add a bit more detail?

Comment: if it's worth an upvote ;-)

Comment: there you go... feel free to expand on other answers... detailed answers might get you even more votes...

Comment: You can now change the font thanks to this patch https://developer.blender.org/D2424 It is not implemented oficially so you need to compile the Blender with that patch applied or download my release
https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B_aeMwO9RVB2SklrUUJrUThHaHM&export=download
The release is missing Cuda support though.

Comment: And finally we have [font selection](https://www.blendernation.com/2019/01/15/blender-developers-meeting-notes-14-january-2019/) support in 2.8 :-)

Answer (score 9):

Edited: There is now a built in VSE text subtitle tool. But it has limited functionality for adding text to a screen. Edited: Apparently now you can word wrap the contents of your text entry string. And you still can change the font but not the direction of the drop shadow.

To make more elaborate supers (superimposed text), you must create a another scene and add it's scene strip to the VSE edit scene. However this is inefficient, I would recommend rendering and text to image files first.

Comment: I think, some answers are just worth an upvote ;-)

Comment: The word wrapping has been [added](https://developer.blender.org/rB0aa0a1a) in 2.77.

Comment: You can now change the font thanks to this patch https://developer.blender.org/D2424 It is not implemented oficially so you need to compile the Blender with that patch applied or download my release
https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B_aeMwO9RVB2SklrUUJrUThHaHM&export=download
The release is missing Cuda support though.

Comment: Dont you know if there´s a .py to load the modification of the font @JanKadeřábek ?