# How would I attach text to a tracked point on video clip

Tags: tracking, text-object

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 and Blender 2.72b.

I've got a video clip where I want to display some annotation-like text next to some potatoes on a white table. The potatoes move a little in the video so I would need to adjust the text a bit every few frames.

(I am a total beginner, I have not used Blender's clip editor before.)

How would I attach text to a tracked point (to the potato) and manually adjust the text's location when required?

Comment: track the object you want ont the video clip editor, link an empty ot the tracker and partent it to your text object something like this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36674/2d-elf-yourself-effect-animate-photo-of-faces-over-80s-cartoon-intro/36680#36680

Comment: @cegaton I can handle starting tracking a object but how do I make it stop tracking the object and remove the annotation after a certain frame? How do I create the text object, do I have to make a .png with the text and then somehow import that to Blender?  (Sorry for asking so much questions, it's all new for me)

Comment: starting with blender? bookmark end explore the following link: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Comment: Text is created using "add text" in the 3D scene https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/texts/index.html?highlight=text

Comment: moving potatoes... I've never seen one... are those wild potatoes?

Comment: You should upgrade to the latest version of Blender (2.75a at the moment 2.76 will be coming out soon).

Comment: My answer [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36417/can-i-easily-add-text-to-a-movie/36422#36422) might be useful.

Comment: @cegaton Potatoes are still, the camera moves :).

Comment: To do this on the compositor read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/73551/1853

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's say you've successfully tracked an object in your scene:

[image]

Go to the *Solve Tab* and in the *Geometry* section and click on *Link Empty To Track*.

[image]

That will create an Empty that, if seen from the camera, moves within the frame like the tracked object.

[image]

At this point you might want to add your image as background for reference and make it visible for the camera axis.

Add a text object in the 3d View (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> *> Text* ) and select the *Align to View* option:

[image]

Edit your text, set the orientation to view and place it where you need it.

[image]

Select your text object, then select the Empty by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and simply parent it to the Empty 
(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>).

The text will now move like the tracked object.

[image]

To render both images create a node tree like this:

[image]

**If the text element is an image and not a 3D object**

You can overlay the background video with the foreground element using the compositor:

[image]

The text (with a transparent background) is placed and scaled with a transform node.

The result of that is then passed to a translate node that uses the information from the tracker (select the video used and the object, usually "camera" and the tracker you want to use to control the movement)

[image]

Then use an Alpha over to overlay the image on top of the video background.

Tracked image in the  Movie Clip editor:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Was a gif really necessary to show how to [parent](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26109/2217) something? Or was this comment just a reason to post yet another link to my answer? :)

Comment: @David I'll link to your answer (even if you just have static images)

Comment: How do you set a video as a reference background? I tried following a tutorial on youtube but nothing appeared in the 3D view.

Comment: @Avamander http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/122/1853

Comment: @cegaton Okay, the background image appeared. I also set the camera right. It's going great :D. Altho, would I have to create five node trees for every trackable text point?

Comment: No need to add nodes. I don't know what you mean by every trackable text point.