# Plane track does not follow marker through duration of frames

Tags: tracking

I make stop motion animation, and am trying to figure out how to overlay a mouth on a pattern I have for a characters mouth.

Everything is working as it should with the compositing, etc, aside from my plane track. The plane track will not follow the markers that I have placed on the character's mouth. I made a series of markers, traced it over the camera movements, and then merged them.

I then copied and pasted the marker 3 times over to have the required 4 markers to create the plane track.

Once the plane track is created, it appears for the first frame, but any frame past that point it disappears....

What am I doing wrong here?

Image attached of first frame with the plane tracker present. The following frames only show the marker.

Thanks,
Ben[image]

UPDATE:

After following the steps on the suggested link ([How would I attach text to a tracked point on video clip](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38549/how-would-i-attach-text-to-a-tracked-point-on-video-clip/38557#38557))

I get the following:

[image]

Comment: It is unclear to me why you merge different trackers, also what do yo mean when you say  that you copied and pasted the "marker"

Comment: I merge them because the mouth moves fairly quickly as the character's head moves. With 12 different track points the plane track does not accurately follow the spot. When I say I copied and pasted the 'marker', I'm referring to the track points needed for the plane track. I called them markers because the option in the track tab says "marker". Sorry for the confusion

Comment: If you are going to use the information from only one tracked point then it makes no sense to have a plane track, as you are not providing any information to deform such plane. If you only want to move an image using a single tracked feature, then use the translation information from a tracker to move an image in the compositor. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38549/how-would-i-attach-text-to-a-tracked-point-on-video-clip/38557#38557

Comment: Just saw that your message had more. Thank you. I'll reply if I have any more questions.

Comment: @cegaton I have used your reference. I have it set up to the composite settings for the section titled, "if the text element is an image and not a 3D Object", yet I have an error showing up. I have pasted it in the original question post. Let me know if you have a solution. Thanks

Comment: please don't just put an image with no explanation on what we are looking at.

Comment: I'm confused. I followed your link in your comment and did what it said to do. My image is saying this is the result on my end when I did what your instructions said to do..I don't get a physical error message from Blender itself - Im saying the result is not what I want. The result is an error.

Comment: Can you upload the blend file and the elements you are using to a file sharing site?

Comment: Also, adding CG elements to be keyed out with a color key is not a good idea, you should create elements with an alpha channel for this kind of tasks.

Comment: @cegaton I figured it out. Wanted to say thank you so much for your help. Really appreciate you taking time out of your day.

Comment: please write a detailed answer to your own question. Other users with a similar question will appreciate it and can learn from your experience. Read: [Can I answer my own question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: (And green screen should only be used for in-camera elements to be keyed. For CG elements use a proper alpha channel. It will save you a lot of headaches)