# How to make a text object show dimensions of an object?

Tags: scripting, drivers, dimensions

I'm working on a way to make a semi-automatic system for visualisizng dimensions

[image: semi-automatic dimensions visualisation system]

One last thing I need is to make the text boxes automatically contain the wireframe cube's X, Y and Z dimensions (not scale) with units and 2 decimal point precision like this:

2.56 cm
7.2 mm
10 m

Comment: Is your question about how to set the text of a text object, or how to get the dimensions of an mesh object?

Comment: One way to update text http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6973/15543 To display units http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1071/15543.

Comment: pycoder - my question is about how to get the dimensions, express them in human-readable form and write them automatically to text objects when the "bounding box" object changes dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

```
#ob is the object you want to measure
#x_ob,y_ob,z_ob are the three text objects
(x,y,z) = ob.dimensions.to_tuple()
x_ob.data.body = str(x)
y_ob.data.body = str(y)
z_ob.data.body = str(z)
```

If you want to use the metric system, you can add this:

```
bpy.context.space_data.context = 'SCENE'
bpy.context.scene.system = 'METRIC'
```

If you want the correct unit you can make this kind of function:

```
def units(x):
    if int(x) > 0:
        u = "m"
        y = x
    elif x*100 > 0:
        u = "cm"
        y = x*100
    else:
        u = "mm"
        y = x*1000
    return str(y)+" "+u
```

Comment: That's a lot easier than [building these](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/35360/5334)!

Comment: I mean [these](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/35436/5334)

Comment: Ok, but how do I make this script run automatically every time I change the dimensions of the *ob*?

Should I use a driver or what?